# What is the pattern of extending createStore of Redux with enhancers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns, redux, store

While writing a blog post about decoupling Redux state from components, I have noticed the usage of `enhancer` used in `createStore` [link](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/src/createStore.js#L37):

```js
export default function createStore(reducer, preloadedState, enhancer) {
  /* .... */
  if (typeof enhancer !== 'undefined') {
    if (typeof enhancer !== 'function') {
      throw new Error('Expected the enhancer to be a function.')
    }

    return enhancer(createStore)(reducer, preloadedState)
  }
  /* ... */
  return store;
}
```

The generic pattern, accordingly, is:

```js
function func(arg1, /* ... */, argN, enhancer) {
  /* .... */
  if (typeof enhancer === 'function') {    
    return enhancer(func)(arg1, /* ... */, argN);
  }
  /* ... */
  return result;
}
```

I was excited about this. Now I am wondering how would you classify / name it, and whether it is an ad-hoc excellent piece of code or a result of some systematic approach that is part of something bigger that I'd like to learn and start to apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would call this a [Decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Comment: hey thanks for response! It an interesting candidate, although not matching exactly to the definition.

Comment: It doesn't look like it, but I believe the goal and the mechanism are highly comparable.